# azure pipeline option selector script

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have project that required from me to execute a remote automation on some machine .
so me steps are

- checkout the code
- run command line

> cd .\MatrixPro\TestFramework python .\main.py -t
>   class_test.name_test

As I tried to improve my pipeline I'm trying to build new select parameter that when I'm going to run the pipeline and inject value that I option from the select.

I found that I have few issues at this point

1. how to build the select option
2. how to attach my script to take a list from my api 
   GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=5.1

Comment: 1. use a parameter? 2. use curl?

Comment: @shaharnakash `how to build the select option` I don't quite clear what you want to achieve.Can you describe it in detail? What is the role of the command used above?

Comment: I'm trying to receive data into list , that I will use in the next steps, for reference in jenkins you could save to a parameter a list from API